# Php shows html codes instead of render it on mac and IOS

Tags: php, html, ios, css, macos

I have a live site http://secure.lowendticket.com/ having issue with it shows proper output on other platform like windows,linux(chrome,firefox) , But it shows HTML codes and tags on iPhone ,iPad and other apple devices .
you can show meta tags using source-code.
please see this attachment[image]

Comment: If it's secure, why isn't it an `https://`?

Comment: Also, it's taking forever to load.

Comment: your page returns a very weird content type `"text/html application/x-httpd-php .php .php5"` which probably breaks it on some devices, as that is used to decide how to render the content

Comment: LoL ,@TricksfortheWeb its name of domain http://secure.lowendticket.com/ ,